# how to append ascending number in string java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a user name. I have created one request class like this:

```
private String userId;
@NotNull
@Size(max = 20, min = 8)
private String password;
@NotNull
@Email
private String email;
@NotNull
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String middleName;
private String organization;
```

I am doing

```
String userName = user.getFirstName().toLowerCase().charAt(0) + "_" + user.getLastName() + "_"
            + user.getOrganization();
```

For example: FirstName: John LastName: Parkar organization: google so userName: jparkar_google

But if same user name is present in DB it should append number at the last.

Now if

FirstName: John LastName: Parkar organization: google then userName should come as: jparkar_google1

Again if FirstName: John LastName: Parkar organization: google then userName should come as; jparkar_google2

So how to append this 1,2,3,... while creating new name while having same name if present in database.

Comment: Check the database if the username is present and append a number ;)

Comment: Query your database to get the count duplicate names, something like: `select count(*) from table_name where firstName = 'name'` for example. If the result of this query is greater than 0, add that result + 1 and append it to your string

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve that you should check the database first and if there is such user add a counter. You can do it in many ways but that adds logic to your code and you get meaningless usernames.

I would suggest another approach. Use the email for username!

1. It is unique by design. If it is the same email then it is the same person.
2. It usually have kind of the format you have - firstname.lastname@company
3. People already know it and won't have to remember that they are jParkerGoogle16

Comment: This approach is good. What if two users are created having same email-id. Because it can happen

Comment: See my first point. If they have the same email they are the same person. If someone wants two accounts - make them use a different email for that. That's widely used pattern ;) Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: Yeah I saw the first point. Its better to use emailid rather than having temp variable

Answer (score 0):

Below steps should help you tackle this problem. How you're going to write that code relies on you.

1. Write a method that returns the user when given a username
2. If a user is returned from the database create a counter and set it to 1
3. Append said counter to the username and save it into a temporary variable
4. If a user is returned increment the counter and go to 3)
5. Set the temporary username into the user and save said user to the database